# perl script to replace the xml values

Tags: perl, xml-parsing

I have this XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<BroadsoftDocument protocol = "OCI" xmlns="C" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <sessionId xmlns="">169.254.52.85,16602326,1324821125562</sessionId>
    <command xsi:type="UserAddRequest14sp9" xmlns="">
        <serviceProviderId>AtyafBahrain</serviceProviderId>
        <groupId>LoadTest</groupId>
        <userId>user_0002@atyaf.me</userId>
        <lastName>0002</lastName>
        <firstName>user</firstName>
        <callingLineIdLastName>0002</callingLineIdLastName>
        <callingLineIdFirstName>user</callingLineIdFirstName>
        <password>123456</password>
        <language>English</language>
        <timeZone>Asia/Bahrain</timeZone>
        <address/>
  </command>
</BroadsoftDocument>
```

and I need to replace the values of some fields (UserID, firstName, password) and output the file to be saved with the same name.

Using the code below I will change the syntax of the xml fields (xml format gets disturbed):

```
XMLout(     $xml,     KeepRoot => 1,     NoAttr => 1,     OutputFile => $xml_file, );
```

can you please advice how to edit the xml file without changing its syntax?

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout XML::Simple parser for perl. You can refer to the CPAN site. I have used it for parsing XML files but I think this should allow modification as well.

Answer (score -1):

```
# open XML file (input the XML file name)
open (INPUTFILE, "+<$filename_1");    
@file = <INPUTFILE>;
seek INPUTFILE,0,0;
foreach $file (@file)
{
    # Find string_1 and replace it by string_2
    $file =~ s/$str_1/$str_2/g;

    # write to file
    print INPUTFILE $file;   
}
close INPUTFILE;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Although, doing regular expression substitutions on XML is not a good idea. It would be easy to make the whole bunch invalid with some `<` characters. Also your code doesn't compile under [strict](http://p3rl.org/strict)ures and today the three-argument form of `open` is preferred.